# script stop working when sending often post

Tags: php

Does anyone here have experienced like this

Scenario:
I have a form and text area.in this text area i putted data every line.
The data will send post itself then it read every line of textarea and send post to other url then the other url will send response.

This is working if i submit below 10 lines on textarea and if i submit more than 10 lines the script stop working and send me to 500.shtml page.

I wonder that my server have limit.
Because when i tried to my locahost it is working.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: can you check your web server error log? HTTP error code 500 is `Internal server error`

Comment: If php then the related setting variable is post_max_size but I doubt it will be the issue for a text area content. Still you can check the actual value with phpinfo() and likely increase.

Comment: @bansi on error log i got this exec used but not allowed in /home/User/public_html/500.shtml but when i tried to access 500.shtml i got this msg [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Comment: @smozgur the post max size is 10M,i already change it on my whm panel.each line on text have 10 characters.alsi i trim it every line.im wondering why this script works on my localhost any idea?

Comment: you should check the error before the error you mentioned. the error you mentioned is happening because you have enabled custom error handler and not provided the file. If you are not having any error before this, you should enable error logging in PHP.

Comment: Oh i tried on different hosting and everything works fine.im hosting bluehost vps any idea why this happen?and what setting that i need to change?

Comment: @bansi there is no error that logs on my error_log on public_html when i try to execute my script.

Comment: You should contact your hosting provider. error_log file location is normally not in public_html because it is open to public and the log file can have very sensitive data. it should be normally in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: Thanks to all bansi and smozgur for replying my thread.i figured it out.if anyone experience like this.you must switch the php 5 handler to cgi not fcgi.to do thi go to whm panel/service configuration/configure PHP and suEXEC/ change the php 5 handler from fcgi to cgi and viola it works.i dont know if there are any way to configure this without accessing whm panel..anyway how do i mark this thread as solved?